# ProMotion Styling Table Cells with Teacup

Tags: uitableview, rubymotion, teacup

I've looked all over for the Google answer to this, but no joy. What I'd like to do is mix and match Teacup and ProMotion for tables. The overall table is pretty easy. Just add this to the hash for the data element in the `table_data` method.

```
stylename: :leg_cell
```

-and-

```
Teacup::Stylesheet.new :main_screen do
  style :leg_cell,
    backgroundColor: UIColor.colorWithRed(238, green:238, blue:238, alpha: 1),
    textColor: UIColor.greenColor
  style UITableViewLabel,
    textColor: UIColor.greenColor
end
```

for the stylesheet. But... `UITableViewLabel` is being ignored and there's this:

[image]

Symbiote tells me this is a UITableViewLabel, but I'm not seeing a way to style it. Also, Teacup offers these neat:

```
layout do
  # things here to add styled subviews
```

things that are very similar to the subview adding thingies in ProMotion. How (well) do these coexist?

Any hints on how to get that tableview label styled green? And perhaps even use TeaCup to add some custom UILabels?

Note: I know the green is awful, but I'm using it just to demonstrate that I've got the right element styled. I'll pick something more tasteful once I'm getting the styling correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend subclassing PM::TableViewCell (which is a subclass of UITableViewCell) and applying your Teacup styling in there.

```rb
class MyTableViewCell < PM::TableViewCell
  attr_accessor :mileage_label

  stylesheet :main_screen
  def layoutSubviews
    layout do
      # Subviews
      # Apply `self.mileage_label` to your UILabel here.
    end
    restyle! # May be necessary?
  end
end

class MyScreen < PM::TableScreen
  def table_data
    [{
      cells: [{
        cell_class: MyTableViewCell,
        title: "whatever",
        properties: {
          mileage_label: "My mileage label",
        }
      }]
    }]
  end
end
```

Comment: So in this context, say my `PM::TableViewCell` has a `UILabel` subview called `mileage_label`. How do I specify the text for `mileage_label` in my `table_data` hash?

Comment: Updated my code example to show how. You add an `attr_accessor` and then can refer to that in your table_data hash.

Comment: I'm trying something similar but getting this error ```"In NavigationScreen#table_data, you should set :event_name, :today in a `properties:` hash. See TableScreen documentation."```. I'm using event_name and today instead of milage_label but otherwise it's mostly the same.

Comment: Also, when I try to add a stylesheet line it fails on compile with this error ```Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'undefined method `stylesheet' for EventCell:Class (NoMethodError)```. This is my class declaration line: ```class EventCell < PM::TableViewCell```.

Comment: @Dan - I updated the example. You want to use the `properties` hash now in newer versions of ProMotion. Not sure what the second error is -- please file an issue!